# Android Thumbnail creation, Who does it?

Tags: android

In android, Who creates the thumnails?

I have an app where i am acessing the thumnail database. I observe that after loading the new images in the sdcard, some of the images get missed in my app.

So is it the media scanner who creates and updates the Thumbnail database?
Is there a way to force it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rescan media.
After taking picture try calling insert() function of [ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#insert%28android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) passing the information about the picture.

```
public final Uri insert (Uri url, ContentValues values)
```

It will actually add the picture to the database and create picture's thumbnail image for you. It will also be added to the thumbnail database. Hope this helps!

**OR**

Try this code :

```
public static void scanFile(Context context, String path, String mimeType ) {
    Client client = new Client(path, mimeType);
    MediaScannerConnection connection = new MediaScannerConnection(context, client);
    client.connection = connection;
    connection.connect();
}

private static final class Client implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {
    private final String path;
    private final String mimeType;
    MediaScannerConnection connection;

    public Client(String path, String mimeType) {
        this.path = path;
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        connection.scanFile(path, mimeType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        connection.disconnect();

}

}
```

Then just call `scanFile(imageUri.getPath(), null)`.

Don't use encoded path and don't use "*/*" as a MIME type because null value makes scanner to determine MIME type automatically.